# Configuração SSL no Microsoft Azure para projetos Java rodando em tomcat

Tags: java, spring, microsoft-azure, ssl, https

Preciso fazer uma configuração HTTPS em um projeto java no azure. No projeto eu uso spring security e tomcat. Procurei em muitos sites como fazer a configuração mas encontrei diferentes informações, o que me deixou um pouco perdido e tentei configurar de várias formas.

Fiz a configuração no tomcat 9 para aceitar requisição na porta 8443 https e usei o keytool para gerar uma csr e depois usei a mesma para adquirir o certificado do CA Goodaddy. Lá consegui baixar 3 arquivos para tomcat e usei o keytool para definir root o certificado principal e os intermediarios.

Isso imagino ser essa a principal configuração que fiz, mas tentei outras coisas também. 
Se alguém que já configurou https no azure souber ilustrar o passo a passo que deve ser feito para tonar um projeto java certificado, ficarei muito grato.

Comment: Como esta tentando fazer a hospedagem? Vc esta tentando usando IaaS e subiu uma VM, ou esta usando PaaS com Azure App Service, como o Azure WebApp?

Comment: Subi uma VM e estou tentando fazer a configuração direto no tomcat, usando o keytool.

Comment: Pois entao, eh que assim vc tera que buscar orientacao sobre tomcat, sobre o SO da VM e ACL para liberar portas, etc. Mas se vc hospedar PaaS com Azure AppService WebApp, posso te orientar a instalar o certificado SSL rapidamente.

Comment: Blz, vamos tentar então. Vou ter que alterar algumas coisas no meu código, pois nessa modalidade eles oferecem apenas o Java 7 e eu estava usando o 8. Se você puder me passar as orientações eu mudo para PaaS aqui e faço as alterações necessárias.

Answer (score 1):

Como conversado nos comentarios, para adicionar um certificado SSL usando Azure App Service WebApp, basta ir na opcao SSL Certificates, faer upload do seu certificado e pronto. Ja poderas acessar usando HTTPS.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]